# Javascript algorithm for crafting game

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a game in which we harvest components. These components combine with each other to give either rewards or other components. The list of recipes is known.

I wish to be able to enter the components in my possession as well as the quantity, and to be able to retrieve the list of possible rewards (taking into account the components created from others).

I don't really know where to start to be able to obtain the possible combinations according to the components I have in the game.

An idea?

EDIT:
Here my first work.
The data and the function call

```
const recipes = {
        "recipe_1": {
          "components": [
            "component1",
            "component2"
          ],
          "type" : "reward",
          "result": "reward1"
        },
        "recipe_2": {
          "components": [
            "component1",
            "component3"
          ],
          "type" : "component",
          "result": "component4"
        },
        "recipe_3": {
          "components": [
            "component3",
            "component4"
          ],
          "type" : "component",
          "result": "component5"
        },
        "recipe_4": {
          "components": [
            "component4",
            "component5"
          ],
          "type" : "reward",
          "result": "reward2"
        }
    }
    
    const inventory = {
        "component1" : 23,
        "component2" : 12,
        "component3" : 6,
        "component4" : 3,
        "component5" : 7
    }

    craft(recipes, inventory)
```

The recursive function I made

```
    function craft(recipes, inventory){
    // Loop over all recipes
    for (let recipe of Object.entries(recipes)){
        //Make a modifiable copy of inventory
        let inv = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(inventory))
        let count = 0
        // Loop for count how many craft we can make
        while(((inv[recipe[1].components[0]]) > 0 ) && ((inv[recipe[1].components[1]]) > 0)){
            count++
            // Remove used components
            inv[recipe[1].components[0]] -= 1
            inv[recipe[1].components[1]] -= 1
            // Add component if recipe craft a component
            if(recipe[1].type == 'component'){
                inv[recipe[1].result] += 1
            }
        }
        // if we can craft, output what we can craft
        if(count > 0){
            console.log(`Can Craft ${count} ${recipe[1].result} / ${recipe[0]} / ${recipe[1].components}`)
        }
        // Delete recipe to avoid infinite loop
        delete recipes[recipe[0]]
        // recursive function
        craft(recipes, inv)
    }
}
```

For now, I have a doubt about the accuracy of the recursive function.
My wish would be able to detail the way for the craft. For exemple, if you can craft 3 component5, you have to craft 3 component3 and 3 component4, and for craft these, you have to craft 3 component3 you have to craft 3 componentX etc etc.

I'm a little lost in the logic of the recursive function.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: When you tried to implement this where did you get stuck? Or how do you think it _might) work? We're not here to do the work for you, we're here to help you learn what you did wrong when you tried. Also a bit of code that has example function (even if it has no implementation) and it's expected return value would help make the question a lot easier to answer.

Comment: Hello, @AlexWayne far be it from me to make you do my work, I just edited my post with some exemples and code for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

```
function canCraft(item) {
   let inv = inventory.clone();
   let todo = {item: 1};
   // subtract everything subtractable from inventory
   for (let k of Object.keys(todo)) {
      if (inv[k] > 0) { let d = Math.min(inv[k], todo[k]); inv[k] -= d, todo[k] -= d; if (todo[k][k] == 0) delete todo[k] }
   }
   // split items not in inventory
   for (let k of Object.keys(todo)) {
      let n = todo[k]; todo[k] = 0;
      if (!recipes[k]) return `can't craft missing ${k} raw item`
      for (let ing of Object.keys(recipes[k])) {
         todo[ing] ??= 0; todo[ing] += n * recipes[k][ing];
      }
   }
   // so the item is now split into ingrediends, and you can repeat above steps until you either out of todo or find a missing raw item
}
```